# Asana API - Total record count

Tags: asana-api

I am integrating Asana project metrics with our help desk dashboard.  I would like to show 3 numbers for each project:
- Total tasks in project
- Total completed tasks in project
- Total incomplete tasks in project

When I call the project/tasks api, I want to simply get a count, and not have to retrieve all the pages and programatically count the tasks.  Is there any parameter for the API calls which just gets me a count of how many tasks match the criteria?

Thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Asana API doesn't currently have the type of filtering where you can query to a subset of tasks that match an arbitrary pattern that you specify (i.e. "only the tasks where completed=true"). We also don't have an easy way to only get the completed tasks. You can get all incomplete tasks fairly easily by specifying `completed_since=now` on the [tasks query endpoint](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks#query) - which is admittedly a bit strange, but works - but its converse (get only completed tasks) doesn't.

We are evaluating use cases for more filtering options, so you might see it at some point! For now, however, the only way to go about this is to get all of the tasks for a project and count them on your side.